# "It should have come down" or "It should have came down"?

Tags: past-tense, verb-forms, past-participles

My colleague and I were talking and he said "it should have **came** down", which to me, does not sound correct. Which sentence is correct?

I also have a question about 'took' and 'taken'. With the same individual, he said "he could have **took** the cookie" to which I corrected him and said that, yes, you can say that and the meaning will come across and will be understandable, but "he could have **taken** the cookie" is correct English. In retrospect, after much debate, I am now doubting myself.

By my knowledge of the English language, 'took' and 'taken' are not interchangeable if you are utilising the English language correctly.

Comment: The number of students in American colleges and universities who make this particular error when speaking (and even when writing) might suprise you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructions you are quoting are of the **should have** + **past participle** type.

> (wrong) It should have **came** down.

Here, the verb *to come* is used in its [preterite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preterite) ("simple past") form, which is wrong.

> (right) It should have **come** down.

Here, the verb *to come* assumes its [past participle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Past_participle) form, as it should after **should have**.

The same is true with **could have took** (wrong) and **could have taken** (right). In short, you were right in both cases.

Why? Because the modal verb *should* and the verb *have* play auxiliary roles (they are "[auxiliary verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb)"). The carry some information, and the verb coming after them is left to carry the rest.

The auxiliary verb **have** already tells us that the action is in the past, so we don't need the *simple past* form of the verb **to come**. We need to attach a "weaker" verb after the **have**, a verb that merely carries the information about the kind of the action (to come) and not about the time of the action. Otherwise, we would have a "much of a muchness" situation.

The Past Participle is such "weaker form": [a non-finite verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonfinite_verb#Participles).